# Embedding of ordered sets?

Tags: proof-writing, order-theory, proof-explanation

Let $(E,<)$ a well-ordered set.
Let $g\colon(E,{<})\to(E,<)$ an embedding of ordered sets.

I have to show that $\forall e\in E, e\le g(e)$.

The hint is to consider the set $C=\{\,e\in E \mid e>g(e)\,\}$ but I don't understand what informations it gives.

Then how many embeddings there are in $(E,<)$ ? Just the trivial one ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: As Hagen von Eitzen's and Brian Scott's answers note, $E$ can have many self-embeddings (if and only if it's infinite, in fact, and then there are $2^{\lvert E \rvert}$). However, a well-ordered set has only one automorphism (order isomorphism to/from itself). That is an easy consequence of the result you have to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If the theorem were false, the set $C$ would be a non-empty subset of $E$ and would therefore have a least element $c$ with respect to the well-order $<$. Use $c$ to get a contradiction by showing that $g$ is not order-preserving.

$E$ can have many embeddings. Take $E=\Bbb N$. Then for each $k\in\Bbb N$ the map $n\mapsto n+k$ is an embedding, for instance. In fact there are $2^\omega=\mathfrak{c}=|\wp(\Bbb N)|$ embeddings of $\Bbb N$ into itself, since for each infinite $A\subseteq\Bbb N$ there is an embedding $f_A:\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ such that $f_A[\Bbb N]=A$.

Answer (score 1):

The hint is to consider $C$. Note that you want to show that $C=\emptyset$. So assume $C\ne\emptyset$. What can be said about non-empty subsets of a well-ordered sets? What can you conclude?

Re your second question: $x\mapsto 7x^2+5$ is a non-trivial embedding $(\Bbb N,<)\to (\Bbb N,<)$.

Comment: As the set is well-ordered we have the existence of $c$ the minimum of $C$. We have by applying $g$, $c>g(c)$. Moreover $g(g(c))<g(c)<c$ and $g(c)\in C$ contradiction with the definition of $c$ ?